# Solucionar bucle infinito

Tags: c, while

En el else if, no puedo darme cuenta de como salir del bucle infinito. Me explico. Es un programa de solo meter valores numericos. Quiero poder hacer que si mete un tipo caracter, tire un mensaje y vuelva a pedir que ingrese un numero. No me doy cuenta -_-

```
do{
        printf("Ingrese el precio de su producto: ");
        scanf("%f", &producto);
        
        if(producto>0){
            suma = suma + producto;
        }
        else if(producto == letra){
            printf("Solo valores numericos");
        }
        /*
        DESCRUBRIR COMO EVITAR QUE SE META EN UN BUCLE INFINITO
        AL ESCRIBIR UN CARACTER
        */      
    }while(producto!=0);
```

---

Edit:
Ya pude solucionarlo. Cree una variable nueva para el contador del else if, pero ahora no puedo pedirle de vuelta el dato.

```
do{
        printf("Ingrese el precio de su producto: ");
        scanf("%f", &producto);
        
        if(producto>0){
            suma = suma + producto;
        }
        else if(producto == letra){
            printf("Solo valores numericos\n");
            x = x + letra;
        }   
    }while(producto!=0);
```

Comment: de donde viene la variable 'letra'?

Comment: Estas son las variables declaradas: 

    float producto, total, desc;
    int suma, x;
    char letra;
    suma = 0;`

Comment: En vez de utilizar la variable producto para terminar la ejecución, crea un flag booleano como por ejemplo salir, cuando este en true termina la ejecución de tu programa, en el else if le puedes poner por ejemplo un mensaje de quiere continuar o salir y ahi seteas tu flag a true si quiere terminar.

Answer (score 2):

Esta lectura

```
scanf("%f", &producto);
```

Intenta obtener un número del buffer `stdin`. Aquí hay que pensar que `stdin` almacena caracteres. Si el primer caracter que encuentra `scanf` no es convertible a número, `scanf` fallará y devolverá un 0. El buffer `stdin` no se verá alterado.

Si, posteriormente, vuelves a realizar una lectura de un número, esa lectura fallará igualmente, ya que el caracter problemático seguirá en `stdin`. Para salir del bucle debes limpiar el buffer de entrada:

```
while (scanf("%f", &producto) == 0)
{
    while ( getchar() != '\n' );
    puts("Solo valores numericos\n");
}
```

En cualquier caso, piensa que `producto` es de tipo `float`, es decir, **siempre** va a almacenar un número. No hay ninguna forma en la que `numero` pueda decirte que se ha leído un caracter porque, para este tipo, todo son números en coma flotante.